# Flask Blueprint cannot register Nested Blueprint

Tags: python, rest, flask

I am creating an API that have 3 main route

- /api1
- /api2
- /api3

and I would like to have 3 route under api2

- /api2/route1
- /api2/route2
- /api2/route3

So I check for Flask documentation about Nested Blueprint.

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/blueprints/#nesting-blueprints

And I code this:

```
bp1 = Blueprint("api1", __name__, url_prefix="/api1")
bp2 = Blueprint("api2", __name__, url_prefix="/api2")
bp3 = Blueprint("api3", __name__, url_prefix="/api3")

bp2_1 = Blueprint("api2_1", __name__, url_prefix="/route1")
bp2_2 = Blueprint("api2_2", __name__, url_prefix="/route2")
bp2_3 = Blueprint("api2_3", __name__, url_prefix="/route3")

app.register_blueprint(bp1)
app.register_blueprint(bp3)

bp2.register_blueprint(bp2_1)
app.register_blueprint(bp2)
```

When I run it, it show this error

```
AttributeError: 'Blueprint' object has no attribute 'register_blueprint'
```

Is Flask still not support Nested Blueprint? Or what version does it start supporting nested blueprint?
Or how should I achieve Nested Blueprint?

I am using flask version 1.1.2

Answer (score 1):

You have to register the child blueprint before you register the parent to the app.

```
bp2.register_blueprint(bp2_1)
bp2.register_blueprint(bp2_2)
bp2.register_blueprint(bp2_3)

app.register_blueprint(bp2)
```

You could find more details at the Flask [documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/blueprints/#nesting-blueprints).

But I think this is only possible for Flask 2.x. So you have to upgrade your version.